# How can to make a web app project validation fast in eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, xhtml

While I am doing **Project-->clean** to web application in eclipse, validation of XHTML files is very slow.It's taking around 20 minutes to complete the validation.I have 54 XHTML files in my project.

I unchecked all the entires in **window--> preferences-->validations**.It's building very fast but I don't know it's a proper way to bypass validations.I am using Eclipse Indigo version.How can I make eclipse to complete validation fast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

20 minutes to complete validation of 54 XHTML files is certainly problematic. Re-enable all validators, and run Project -> Clean. As Eclipse is re-validating the files, take a few core dumps of Eclipse's JVM; that might shed a light on where, exactly, things are lagging.

My bet is that the validators are trying to access external resources during validations, for example - to download XML schema files or DTD's. If your XHTML files contain references to external resources like those, it is possible that they are the reason for the lag. You could download such DTD's and Schemas, and use Eclipse's *XML Catalog* to bind DTD/Schema references to physical files on your machine (instead of fetching them online).

That's just one theory. To know for sure, though, you'll have to issue core dumps of Eclipse's JVM and look closer.

Comment: @Issac...My XHTML files refers to JSF facelets and other 3 jsf namespaces.It used to be fast but these I am facing this issue and making my life miserable.And how to remove core dumps of Eclipse JVM?

Comment: @Issac.....I guess I figured out the issue. Once I installed `Wso2` webservice plugin, I uninstalled but around 100+ jars still there in plugins folder of the eclipse.Once I removed them It's validating very fast.I am not sure this caused the issue?Do you have any Idea about this kind of situation.

Comment: I am not *that* intimate with Eclipse's internals, but it is possible that Eclipse is looking inside JARs (in its plugins directory) for resolving resources referred-to by validators. An Eclipse core-dump could shed light on that as well. Use `jstack` for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html

Comment: Hey I am still that issue.I thought it's gone after deleting those jars but still issue there.

Comment: ... So follow the instructions, run `jstack` and figure it out from there.

Comment: Ok I will try to figure out.

Comment: The problem is that you can't just "make it work faster"... if it works slow, then its either due to an Eclipse bug or some sort of misconfiguration. `jstack` will help. Post your results when you get them...

Comment: Ok sure I will post the results here. Actually I saw it as a bug as per ecllipse bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377405